# Firebase simultaneous connection limit if adding more listeners

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Our firebase realtime database is reaching it's 100k connection limit.

We have a object with some 30 keys some of them are int & float and are updated more often while the other are string which are updated less frequent.

Right now we fetch the whole node but I'm thinking of dividing the object in 2 parts.

1.one for more often updated but less in size data.
2.Second for less frequent updated, larger in size data.

So we can reduce the database usage.

The question is will the simultaneous connections increase to double? as there will be now 2 listeners instead of 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of connections to Realtime Database is almost certainly **not** going to be related to the types of data you're storing, or the way that data is organized.

Every mobile client establishes exactly one websocket to Realtime Database, and that socket is only active when the app is running in the foreground (and maybe a bit outside of that in some cases).  That socket is considered a single connection, and all traffic between the database and the client go over that socket.  It doesn't matter what data is being transferred - there is only that one socket.

Don't confuse listeners with connections.  All added listeners/observers in an app use the same socket.  Reducing the number of listeners will **not** reduce the number of connections.

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile I was reading about the same but your answer was more clearing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're saying that the number of active listeners has no effect on the number of connections from client. Client can make only one connection. So, can I assume here that adding many small listeners for each child instead of adding one listener for the whole has no adverse effects such as increase on billing, decrease on the speed of data transfer, excessive network usage for client (when the amount of data downloaded is always same regardless of the number of listeners)?

Comment: Take a look at the billing documentation.  Nowhere does it say anything about the number of listeners.  Billing is based on the amount of data transferred.

Comment: Long time Firebase user and while this fact has always been assumed, I've never actually known for sure until stumbling across this answer. Similarly, the kind of optimisations in place (or not) when you e.g. initialise a new app / db in an esm script.  I wonder if this is something that could be highlighted more clearly in the docs? Apologies if I've missed it!